# How to format post body as json?

Tags: json, python-requests

I'm trying to mimic a post request, using python requests.

The post body is

```
nonce=b3272d453ca8734f8df1c78ce201f00c&from=01%2F12%2F22&to=31%2F12%2F22&columns%5B%5D=Transaction.DateTimeConverted&columns%5B%5D=Terminal.Id
```

I have managed to create

```
{"nonce": "b3272d453ca8734f8df1c78ce201f00c",
"from": "01/12/22",
"to": "31/12/22",
"columns"[]: "Transaction.DateTimeConverted"
"columns"[]: "Terminal.Id"
}
```

But something isn't working, I suspect it is around my misunderstanding of percentage enncoding representation in Json, aroud the columns? Can someone help?

Comment: Help us help you - share the code where you're actually sending the request

Answer (score 0):

`"key"[] : "value1", "key"[]: "value2"`  is not valid JSON. you would need to convert it to `"key": [ "value1", "value2" ]`.